# How can i change the year from the calendar when the months value passes december?

Tags: php

I'm building a calendar - I'm making the buttons to change the month and the year.

Every time that the button to go forward is clicked, the variable that contains the months, receives more 1 value.

```
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); //the ID contains the months

$next= $id + 1; //forward button

if($id < 12){

}else{

$id = 1; //puts the id variable back to 1 again
$next = $id;
}
```

Button code:

```
<a href="test.php?id=<?= +$next?>"><button>Next</button></a>
```

Calling the function:

```
echo get_date($id,2014);
```

Now here's the problem: I'm having some problems changing the year when the id reaches december(12).

I tried this:

```
$years = date('Y');

$back = $id - 1; 
$next= $id + 1;

if($id < 12){

}else{

$id = 1;
$next= $id;
$years++;
}
```

And I called the function:

```
echo get_date($id,$years);
```

**get_date function:**

```
  <?php function get_date($month, $year){

      switch ($month) {
        case "1":
        $ex_month = 'January';
        break;
        default:
        $ex_month = 'January';
      }

    ?>

    <div id="calendar-wrap">
    <div class="month-selection"><span><?= $ex_month . ' ' . $year; ?></span></div>

    <a href="?m=back"><<</a></td>
    </div>

    <div class="weeks">
    <?php $weeks = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');?>
    <div class="weeks-begin"><span><?= $weeks[0]; ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?= $weeks[1]; ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?= $weeks[2]; ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?= $weeks[3]; ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?= $weeks[4]; ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?= $weeks[5]; ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?= $weeks[6]; ?></span></div>
    <?php 

    $day = date('d');

    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,0,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;

    ?>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="c-col-1">

    <?php
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):   
    ?>
    <div class="c-empty"></div>
<?php
    endfor;
?>

<?php for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++): 

if($list_day == $day){

$div = '<div style="background: red;">';

}else{
$div = '<div>';
}
?>

<?= $div ?><span> <?= $list_day ?> </span><span class="resp-week"></span></div>

<?php 

endfor;


 ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php } 
?>
```

Comment: Is the problem when you reach December by going from January *or* when you reach December from going from October? If it's the first option, the reason is you haven't implemented that code.

Comment: i want to change the year everytime that the id reaches january again.

Comment: there are very useful classes such as http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php prebuilt with php... rewriting the wheel can get tiresome from time to time, I suggest you look into it :) with this class, adding a month to a date so that it will change year automatically is not even worth thinking about

Answer (score 0):

i already did it, here the solution:

I created a new parameter to get the year.

```
<?php } 

$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 

$get_year = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['year']); 

$teste = 1;

$back = $id - 1; 

$next= $id + 1;

if($id < 12){

}else{
++$teste;
++$get_year;
$id = 1;
$next= $id;

}

?>
<a href="teste.php?id=<?= +$next?>&year=<?= $get_year; ?>"><button class="offersbtn">Next</button></a>
<?php

echo get_date($id,$get_year);
?>
```